# Si l'on vous dit qu'un travail est à rendre pour le 19 décembre à minuit au plus tard

Tags: usage, indications-de-temps, dates

Cela veut il dire qu'il faut rendre le travail le 18 décembre ou le 19 décembre à 23:59:59 au plus tard ?

Answer (score 6):

Point de vue logique, je dirais le

> 19 décembre à 23:59:59

Mentionner la date du 19 alors que la date voulue est le 18 ne causerait que la confusion.

Mais cela est un problème de prof et non de langage.

Answer (score 2):

Cela veut dire *le soir du 19.*

Si on avait dit « le 19 décembre à 0 heure » ce serait alors le soir du 18 (le 18 à minuit).

Answer (score 2):

[Une date] à minuit fait référence à la fin de la journée, pas au début. C'est probablement parce que le 0 n'a été utilisé en Europe que tardivement (il n'existait pas en chiffre romains) et minuit représentait la dernière heure de la journée. D'ailleurs sur les cadrans d'horloges, il est plus courant de voir un 12 (ou un XII en chiffres romain) qu'un 0.

Pour cette raison, jusqu'au 19 décembre à minuit signifie simplement avant le commencement de la journée du 20 décembre.

Comment: Parvenu en Europe seulement aux alentours du XIème siècle. Mais quand même découvert vers le IIIème siècle avant JC.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE: Merci de la précision. J'en ai profité pour corriger mon message.

Answer (score 0):

En général, il s'agit de la dernière heure de la journée, à savoir

> 19 décembre, 23:59:59

Cependant l'expérience montre que cette règle n'est pas toujours observée. Demande une confirmation pour lever l'ambiguïté.